# Why are there duplicates created with full outer join with more than 3 tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Why are there always duplicates created with T-SQL FULL OUTER JOIN with more than 2 tables, when the first table (the FROM table) does not have a key value that at least two other tables have?

```
create table x(a int)
create table y(a int)
create table z(a int)

INSERT INTO x values (0);
INSERT INTO y values (1);
INSERT INTO z values (1);

SELECT x_a=x.a, y_a=y.a, z_a=z.a, a=coalesce(x.a,y.a,z.a)
FROM x as x
FULL JOIN y as y
ON y.a=x.a
FULL JOIN z as z
ON z.a=x.a
ORDER BY a
```

Yeilds:

```
x_a        y_a    z_a   a
0          NULL   NULL  0
NULL        1     NULL  1
NULL       NULL    1    1
```

Thus, we have duplicate key values, which is not what I expect, or what you would get if you joined the tables sequentially or in order of two's. In this case, FULL JOIN is not really associative or communative.

Is there a way to solve this in a programmically efficient manner?

Comment: I don't understand your question :/

Comment: so what is your expected result ?

Answer (score 3):

Let's see.  If you run:

```
SELECT x_a = x.a, y_a = y.a, a=coalesce(x.a, y.a)
FROM x as x FULL JOIN
     y as y
     ON y.a = x.a;
```

You will get two rows, because `y.a` is not equal to `x.a` and `FULL JOIN` keeps all rows in both tables even with no match.  The columns from the unmatched table are all `NULL`.

The rows will be:

```
x_a    y_a    a
0      NULL   0
NULL   1      1
```

That is what happens when the `ON` condition is false for a `FULL JOIN`.

When this is repeated with `z`, you get three rows, because the `ON` condition is also false.

The results make perfect sense to me.

Comment: Can you tell me precisely what you mean when you say 'when this is repeated with z'?  If you  first join x and y, and the take the result and full join it with z, you will get two rows in the final output.  <p>If you are taking the union of the two separate steps, of course you will get 4 rows. </p> I really have no idea what SQL is doing here.

Comment: @JohnSmith . . . If you use `full join` and the condition evaluates to false or `NULL`, then you will get rows from *both* tables.

Answer (score 1):

Each subsequent `full join` should be on the coalesce of all the keys of tables before, i.e. `z.a` should be joined on `coalesce(x.a, y.a)`:

```
SELECT x_a=x.a, y_a=y.a, z_a=z.a, a=coalesce(x.a,y.a,z.a)
FROM x as x
FULL JOIN y as y
ON y.a=x.a
FULL JOIN z as z
ON z.a=coalesce(x.a, y.a)
ORDER BY a
```

The above will give you the result I think you're expecting:

```
x_a        y_a    z_a   a
0          NULL   NULL  0
NULL        1      1    1
```